# How to delete everything after matching string in R?

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of strings like this

```
test <- c("Dcl2_SsHV2L_2_CAAAAG_L003_R1_001", "Dcl2_SsHV2L_2_CAAAAG_L003_R1_001", 
"Dcl2_SsHV2L_2_CAAAAG_L003_R1_001", "Dcl1_SsHV2L_2_GGTAGC_L003_R1_001")
```

I need to delete everything after "SsHV2L" and get only

```
Dcl2_SsHV2L
Dcl2_SsHV2L
Dcl2_SsHV2L
Dcl1_SsHV2L
```

I tried: `gsub("SsHV2L.*","",test)`

what is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: Try `gsub("(?<=_SsHV2L).*","",test,perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: @nicola `Error in gsub("(?<=SsHV2L).*", "", test) : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<=SsHV2L).*', reason 'Invalid regexp'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
gsub("SsHV2L.+$", "SsHV2L", test)
```

Here you grab the "SsHV2L" where there is something after it and then just replace all of that with only "SsHV2L"

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("(^.+SsHV2L)(.+$)","\\1", test)
[1] "Dcl2_SsHV2L" "Dcl2_SsHV2L" "Dcl2_SsHV2L" "Dcl1_SsHV2L"
```

This uses a pattern that has two capture classes, the first on end in hte target string and then only that capture class is kept.