# Deleting everything after after a certain string in R

Tags: r, extract, gsub

I have some data in an object called all_lines that is a character class in R (as a result of reading into R a PDF file). My objective: to delete everything before a certain string and delete everything after another string.

The data looks like this and it is stored in the object all_lines

```
class(all_lines)
"character"


[1] LABORATORY               Research Cover Sheet
[2] Number       201111EZ         Title   Maximizing throughput"
[3] "                                     in Computers
[4] Start Date   01/15/2000 
....
[49] Introduction
[50] Some text here and there
[51] Look more text
....
[912] Citations
[913] Author_1 Paper or journal
[914] Author_2 Book chapter
```

I want to delete everything before the string 'Introduction' and everything after 'Citations'. However, nothing I find seems to do the trick. I have tried the following commands from these posts: [How to delete everything after a matching string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503266/how-to-delete-everything-after-matching-string-in-r) and multiple on-line R tutorials on how to do just this. Here are some commands that I have tried and all I get is the string 'Introduction' deleted in the all_lines with everything else returned.

```
str_remove(all_lines, "^.*(?=(Introduction))")
sub(".*Introduction", "", all_lines)
gsub(".*Introduction", "", all_lines)
```

I have also tried to delete everything after the string 'Citations' using the same commands, such as:

```
sub("Citations.*", "", all_lines)
```

Am I missing anything? Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Is your input a string, or a vector of strings?

Comment: I honestly do not know. I believe it's being read by R as multiple strings. I am working in R studio and in the global environment, its stored under 'Values' and all_lines shows "c(\LABORATORY       Research Cover Sheet\",  \Number      201111EZ              Title    Maximizing throughput\", \"         in Computers\",      [etc...etc].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your variable is vector of character strings.  One element per line in the document.

We can use the `grep()` function here to locate the lines containing the desired text.  I am assuming only 1 line contains "Introduction" and only 1 line contains "Citations"

```
#line numbers containing the start and end
Intro <- grep("Introduction", all_lines)
Citation <- grep("Citations", all_lines)

#extract out the desired portion.
abridged <- all_lines[Intro:Citation]
```

You may need to add 1 or substract 1 if you would like to actually remove the "Introduction" or "Citations" line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can accept a single string as output, you could collapse the input into a single string and then use `gsub()`:

```r
all_lines <- paste(all_lines, collapse = " ")
output <- gsub("^.*?(?=\\bIntroduction\\b)|(?<=\\bCitations\\b).*$", "", all_lines)
```